# Java: Sudoku- increase number of empty spaces causes my code to throw an exception

Tags: java, methods, overlap, sudoku

I'm trying to make a Sudoku game for my project but if i increase the number of empty spaces in the Sudoku `Grid` the code just throws an exception `arrayoutofbounds` but can't figure out where it's coming from. `k` is the number of empty spaces in the grid.

I haven't tried anything because can't figure out what can be done at this kind of problem

Here is the code:

```
package sudoku.puzzle;
import java.util.*;

public class SudokuPuzzle {

    int[] mat[];
    int N; // number of columns/rows. 
    int SRN; // square root of N 
    int K; // No. Of missing digits 

    // Constructor 
    SudokuPuzzle(int N, int K) {
        this.N = N;
        this.K = K;

        // Compute square root of N 
        Double SRNd = Math.sqrt(N);
        SRN = SRNd.intValue();

        mat = new int[N][N];
    }
    // Driver code 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Select Level Of Difficulty \n 1.Easy\n 2.Medium\n 3.Hard");
        String Choice = in .next(); in .close();
        if ("1".equals(Choice) || "Easy".equals(Choice) || "easy".equals(Choice) || "e".equals(Choice) || "E".equals(Choice)) {
            int N = 9, K = 40;
            SudokuPuzzle sudoku = new SudokuPuzzle(N, K);
            sudoku.fillValues();
            sudoku.printSudoku();
        }
        if ("2".equals(Choice) || "Medium".equals(Choice) || "medium".equals(Choice) || "m".equals(Choice) || "M".equals(Choice)) {
            int N = 9, K = 60;
            SudokuPuzzle sudoku = new SudokuPuzzle(N, K);
            sudoku.fillValues();
            sudoku.printSudoku();
        }
        if ("3".equals(Choice) || "Hard".equals(Choice) || "hard".equals(Choice) || "h".equals(Choice) || "H".equals(Choice)) {
            int N = 9, K = 72;
            SudokuPuzzle sudoku = new SudokuPuzzle(N, K);
            sudoku.fillValues();
            sudoku.printSudoku();
        }
    }

    // Sudoku Generator 
    public void fillValues() {
        // Fill the diagonal of SRN x SRN matrices 
        fillDiagonal();

        // Fill remaining blocks 
        fillRemaining(0, SRN);

        // Remove Randomly K digits to make game 
        removeKDigits();
    }

    // Fill the diagonal SRN number of SRN x SRN matrices 
    void fillDiagonal() {

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i = i + SRN)

            // for diagonal box, start coordinates->i==j 
            fillBox(i, i);
    }

    // Returns false if given 3 x 3 block contains num. 
    boolean unUsedInBox(int rowStart, int colStart, int num) {
        for (int i = 0; i < SRN; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < SRN; j++)
                if (mat[rowStart + i][colStart + j] == num)
                    return false;

        return true;
    }

    // Fill a 3 x 3 matrix. 
    void fillBox(int row, int col) {
        int num;
        for (int i = 0; i < SRN; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SRN; j++) {
                do {
                    num = randomGenerator(N);
                }
                while (!unUsedInBox(row, col, num));

                mat[row + i][col + j] = num;
            }
        }
    }

    // Random generator 
    int randomGenerator(int num) {
        return (int) Math.floor((Math.random() * num + 1));
    }

    // Check if safe to put in cell 
    boolean CheckIfSafe(int i, int j, int num) {
        return (unUsedInRow(i, num) &&
            unUsedInCol(j, num) &&
            unUsedInBox(i - i % SRN, j - j % SRN, num));
    }

    // check in the row for existence 
    boolean unUsedInRow(int i, int num) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            if (mat[i][j] == num)
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    // check in the row for existence 
    boolean unUsedInCol(int j, int num) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            if (mat[i][j] == num)
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    // A recursive function to fill remaining  
    // matrix 
    boolean fillRemaining(int i, int j) {
        //  System.out.println(i+" "+j); 
        if (j >= N && i < N - 1) {
            i = i + 1;
            j = 0;
        }
        if (i >= N && j >= N)
            return true;

        if (i < SRN) {
            if (j < SRN)
                j = SRN;
        } else if (i < N - SRN) {
            if (j == (int)(i / SRN) * SRN)
                j = j + SRN;
        } else {
            if (j == N - SRN) {
                i = i + 1;
                j = 0;
                if (i >= N)
                    return true;
            }
        }

        for (int num = 1; num <= N; num++) {
            if (CheckIfSafe(i, j, num)) {
                mat[i][j] = num;
                if (fillRemaining(i, j + 1))
                    return true;

                mat[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Remove the K no. of digits to 
    // complete game 
    public void removeKDigits() {
        int count = K;
        while (count != 0) {
            int cellId = randomGenerator(N * N);

            // System.out.println(cellId); 
            // extract coordinates i  and j 
            int i = (cellId / N);
            int j = cellId % 9;
            if (j != 0)
                j = j - 1;

            // System.out.println(i+" "+j); 
            if (mat[i][j] != 0) {
                count--;
                mat[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // Print sudoku 
    public void printSudoku() {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                System.out.print(mat[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you got is probably a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. That means at some point you try to access a field of an array outside its boundaries.

But I can´t see where `K` could be responsible for that. Can you provide more information about the error? E.g. at which value you get it or in which line.

**EDIT:** The variable `i` int the `removeKDigits()` function exceeds the boundaries of the array if the random generator spits out the value `81`.

Comment: but that does not seems possible as the value of N is 9 beacuse i need a 9x9 grid so even if its 9, the radomgenerator() is called and the value that mation can generate is maxed out at 81 and even if it is 81 the division at i and j will sort it out.....sorry i cant see it correct and if i'm wrong

Comment: yeah i cant see that either but if i decrease the value of k the frequency of exception decreases. like if i put the value of k 70 ill get a grid but after rerunning like 9 to 10 time but if i put the value of k at 20 ill get a grid intently

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
 at sudoku.puzzle.SudokuPuzzle.removeKDigits(SudokuPuzzle.java:211)
 at sudoku.puzzle.SudokuPuzzle.fillValues(SudokuPuzzle.java:71)
 at sudoku.puzzle.SudokuPuzzle.main(SudokuPuzzle.java:56)
Java Result: 1

Comment: I don´t understand the logic behind this calculation out of the `cellId`, but `i` could be `9` and since the size of your array is `9` the value is only allowed to be `0-8`. Also the size of `j` can´t exceed `7`, so the column on the far right will never be edited. Just apply the if-Statement on `i` instead of `j`.

Comment: i donno if should or not but the exceptions are gone and i get a grid instently now Thanks for the help brother still got no idea why it was showing an arryoutofbound exception as it should not exceed the array limits due to the calculation....

Comment: If the random generator spits out 81 and you divide through 9 you will get 9 and 9 exceeds the array boundaries. Glad I could help! :)